# Android in visual studio: System can't find specified path

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I installed xamarin for android development in visual studio 2015 community and I just updated xamarin and now my projects give this error:

```
[I:]:                     Tracking android devices started
[D:]:                     Tracking avd started
[D:]:                     avd watcher *.ini path: 'C:\Users\Shelbone\.android\avd'
[D:]:                     avd watcher android path: 'E:\Android\ANDROI~1\tools\android.BAT'
[D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: 
[I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 0 devices
[D:]:                     avd watcher error: load process of avd devices failed, please check the following error: The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

But, the SDK's are there.
[image: sdk paths]

Any idea what happened?

Comment: Try to move the SDK and NDK to a location that does not include a space in the folder. I would recommend moving them to `C:\Android` or something similar.

Comment: There is already no ' ' in the name.    "E:\Development tools\Android\AndroidSDK"

Comment: From the screenshot it shows a space on `Development tools\`

Comment: You're right, sorry. I was only thinking of the sdk/ndk folders themselves. I moved them and I still get the same error  "avd watcher error: load process of avd devices failed"

Comment: I'm not sure if the installation is fixed, but I installed Mono for Android and it doesn't give an error now...

Comment: Never mind, I still have the error. I updated the post and image to represent the current error and paths.

Answer (score 0):

Providing a value for the JAVA_HOME environment variable fixed the error for me:

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to change the path of the SDK in the Regedit. Currently the SDK path is pointing to Android folder, change it to the Xamarim folder:

1. Start the Regedit.
2. On Regedit go to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Android"
3. List item Find the "Path" String and edit it's value: currently should be "C:\Users[User]\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk", change it to "C:\Users[User]\AppData\Local\Xamarin\MonoForAndroid\AndroidSDK"
4. Restart VS.
5. Don't create viruses for Android. :p